# Issue with using two StartCoroutines in one script

Tags: unity

I'm having a Issue with trying to use multiple StartCoroutines within my Script. I'm having an error at line 50 where is says StartCoroutine does not exist in the current context

```
void OnCollisionExit(Collision theCollision) {
    if ((theCollision.gameObject.tag == "Boost")) {
        movementspeed = 13000;
        //StartCoRoutine (Delay2 ());  error here
        Destroy (theCollision.gameObject);
    }
}

IEnumerator Delay2 () {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    movementspeed = 10000;
}



void OnCollisionEnter(Collision theCollision) {
    if ((theCollision.gameObject.tag == "Wall")) {
        movementspeed = 5000;
        StartCoroutine (Delay ());
    }
}

IEnumerator Delay() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);
    movementspeed = 10000;
}
```

Comment: are you sure its not the capitalization error in "StartCoRoutine"?

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like that! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The correct spelling is `StartCoroutine( ... )`

From Unity: [MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)